# How do I check if a view exists?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to check if a view exists before I actually resolve it. Here is my controller, with some comments on how I'd like it to work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/somethinghere/")
    public String getSomething(Model inModel,
            @RequestParam(value="one", defaultValue=Constant.EMPTY_STRING) String one,
            @RequestParam(value="two", defaultValue = Constant.EMPTY_STRING) String two) {
        String view = one + two;
         if (a view with name equal to one + two exists) {
            return view;
        } else {
            return "defaultview";
        }                
}
```

I want to return a view, but only when I've verified that there is indeed a view with that name defined. How do I do this?

Comment: Views are static, they should not be missing for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider how view resolution is done in Spring. Assuming you are using a `InternalResourceViewResolver`, by default or explicit declaration, an `InternalResourceView` object created and the path to the resource is resolved by concatenating `InternalResourceViewResolver`'s prefix, view name (returned by your hanbdler), and suffix.

That `View` object is returned. Note that with `InternalResourceViewResolver` that object cannot be `null` and therefore [`ViewResolver` chaining](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html#resolveViewName%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) cannot be achieved. The `DispatcherServlet` then uses the returned `View` object's `render()` method to create the HTTP response. In this case it will use a `RequestDispatcher` and forward to it the resource described by the View's name. If that resource doesn't exist, the `Servlet` container will produce a 404 response.

Given all that, unless your `View` is something completely different than a `jsp` or related resource, there's no way to check if the resource exists until the container actually forwards the request with a `RequestDispatcher`.

You will have to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but thought this might be of help to someone. I had a scenario where a CMS was providing the direction as to what view to render for a given content type. In this scenario it was crucial to have something in place for just this circumstance. Below is what I used to handle it.

First I injected the following into my controller

```
@Autowired
private InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver;

@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

Next I added this simple method to check for the existence of a view

```
private boolean existsView(String path) {
    try {
        JstlView view = (JstlView) viewResolver.resolveViewName(path, null);
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        URL resource = servletContext.getResource(view.getUrl());
        return resource != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I used this like so:

```
    if(!existsView("components/" + fragment.getTemplate().getId())) {
        logger.warn("View for component " + fragment.getTemplate().getId() + " Not found. Rendering fallback.");
        return new ModelAndView("components/notfoundfallback");
    }
```

My notfoundfallback.jsp looked like this:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <div class="contact-form__container container">
        <div class="contact-form__content" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
            <div class="contact-form__header">
                <h2>No design for content available</h2>
                <span>
                    You are seeing this placeholder component because the content you wish to see
                    doesn't yet have a design for display purposes. This will be rectified as soon as possible.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps someone in the future. It worked in both standard Spring MVC and SpringBoot MVC.

Thanks,